# Xrandr stopped detecting motherboard outputs

Tags: monitor, xrandr

I have a PC with dual boot windows-linux. I allocated 500 unallogated GB from the ubuntu disk to windows, and this screwed up my ubuntu installation.

I managed to get it working again, but here's the problem: I have two monitors, one on my GPU and one on my motherboard. This works fine in windows and it used to work fine in ubuntu too, but now Xrandr doesn't detect any of the video outputs in the motherboard.

Comment: When you type `xrandr --verbose` do you get any clues?

Comment: No, all the motherboard outputs are still missing